# Finding a function that satisfies following terms regarding it's derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives

What I want to do is to find a function that satisfies the following constrains:

$$f(x)\neq x$$
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f'(0)=1$$
second and higher order derivatives $=0$ as well.

**What would be a matematical way of finding such function, or proving it does not exist?**

What I could come up with is:
$$f(x)=g(x)+x$$
$$g(0)=0$$
$$g'(0)=0$$
$$g''(0)=0$$
And so on, but no idea how to go from there.

Comment: Hint: Maclaurin Series.

Comment: Are you asking if $f''(x) \equiv 0$ plus your initial conditions imply that $f(x) = x$? Then yes as a straightforward application of Rolle's theorem. Or are you asking *just* to have all derivatives at zero equal to zero?

Comment: Sine function works with the three conditions on f

Answer (score 2):

If you mean all the high-order derivatives **at the origin** are zero, then $x + g(x)$ where $g$ is any function that is zero in a neighbourhood of the origin. Or any non-analytic function that vanishes at every finite order at the origin, such as $e^{-1/x^2}$.

If you mean all high-order derivatives are identically zero, then two applications of Rolle's theorem show that $f(x) = x$.